# PHP Curl form Post return server 404 error

Tags: php, curl, post

i am trying to post 3 steps form. in step 1 successfully fetch csrf token and post and server return step 2 where again fetch csrf token and fetch input and send to server but server return 404 error and some time 503 error. in browser whole process work fine. i check with header cookies as well, but no luck.

when i submit post so server take me to error page with 404 error

my step 2 code is . please help me what i am doing wrong

```
$url2 = $myurl;
$cookie= "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_fields));

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
              'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
                                            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
                                            //'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
                                            'Connection: keep-alive',
                                            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
                                            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                            'Content-Length: '.strlen(http_build_query($post_fields)).''
                                            ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

print($html);
```

here is curl info ,

```
[content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 840
    [request_size] => 1781
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 1
    [total_time] => 1.342852
    [namelookup_time] => 4.7E-5
    [connect_time] => 4.7E-5
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.000139
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 19782
    [speed_download] => 14731
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 19782
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.409502
    [redirect_time] => 0.899697
    [redirect_url] => 
    [request_header] => GET /Error/NotFound/ HTTP/1.1

Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=sgtn2gjp3vnwlzbc1o2rynzj; DMVCT=!BUmY9FBUSeg9vX773mngcy6iownJceIg25o7msKCbRyyVGsdwBy8m4hIW/0LMfGBVtSj8+BtUJt5SsY=; __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=9dQ9gm4pcFwkc/QnNu60FNwimLtF6QdGsQUKC+jH08DUVjy6q+LOu3ivRcWXGyIFdp9tmiEf0VBkEmLQsdCb6DWvbqz3I+ifny5z/5V4PgVb1g2bJAjaaIVHCGmFCqQ4t0jTPXcTRwuOoFHx6mV/+hexuqlMgf9jbxAz67AylzU=; akavpau_wr=1487539428~id=f84c8dd5fd74c88b432ad0ea211e66df
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 473
```

Comment: Well, if the page isn't there, then the page isn't there.  What can you do about it?

Comment: page is there, if we go through browser so page redirect to Fee page but if we use curl so page redirect to error page